# Como puedo ejecutar metodos de una clase desde el evento onclick en javascript?

Tags: onclick

Estoy construyendo objetos que crean una barra de herramientas para poder manipularlos mi pregunta es si es posible llamar a los metodos de la clase en el evento onclick de los botones de la barra de herramientas

```
class line {
constructor(){}
toolbar(){
$("#tools").append('
<button onclick="this.toggle()">...</button>
<button onclick="this.remove()">...</button>
.
.
.
')
}
toggle(){}
remove(){}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

La solucion que tengo por el momento es la siguiente aunque preferiria que el metodo de la clase se llamara desde el evento onclick del button ya que es menos codigo y mas legible

```
class line {
     constructor(){}
     toolbar(){
         $("#tools").append('<button id="idtogglebtn">...</button>')

         $("#idtogglebtn").on("click", e => this.toggle())
     }
     toggle(){}
}
```

Comment: Je. No te gusto mi respuesta::)

Comment: El problema con tu solucion implica que cada instancia tiene que tener un nombre unico, el caso es que los objetos en mi codigo se crean en una funcion selectora createShape(shape) por medio de una switch se selecionada el tipo de object a crear sh = new line() o sh = new circle() se agrega a una objeto lista  list.add(sh) se plotea sh.plot() se crea la barra sh.createToolbar() y de esta forma siginifica y aunque se generen nombres unicos para cada object sh1, sh2, ... aun abria otros problemas que resolver y tu solucion en lugar de ayudar complica mas las cosas

Comment: Veo que el segundo trozo de codigo no te funcionó, fue porque la funcion `addEventListener` no accepta el sufijo `on`, por lo que se debe omitir y por un descuido no lo hice. Tambien: ¿Que orden debe tener los bottones toggle y los bottones remove.

Answer (score 0):

### Problema:

El `onclick` no está llamando a la función de la clase `line`, lo que realmente está llamando es a una función de la clase Button(`<button/>`) que no existe y te manda un error.

### Posibles soluciones:

Las únicas tres forma que veo para que puedas hacer lo que quieres es:
1: Poner un string que indica el nombre de la instancia( Nota: La instancia debe estar en un ámbito global para poder llamarla desde el evento:

```JavaScript
name_instancia.toolbar("name_instancia");
....
class line{
    toolbar(this_name){
        $("#tools").append('<button onclick=" '+this_name+'.toggle()">...</button> '+
            '<button onclick=" '+this_name+'.remove();">...</button>'
        );
    }
    ...
}
```

2: Agrégale un `class` a los botones(Los `remove` le agrega un class como `btn-removes` y a los `toggle` le agrega un class como `btn-toggles`) y después de crear el elemento usando JavaScript obtenemos los dos botones:

```JavaScript
let toggles=$("#tools .btn-toggles");
let removes=$("#tools .btn-removes");
for (let i in toggles){
    toogle[i].addEventListener("click",this.toggle);
}
for (let i in removes){
    removes[i].addEventListener("click",this.remove);
}
```

3: Creando los botones como hijo o `appendChild(createElement("button));`:

```JavaScript
class line{
    toolbar(father=$("#tools")){
        for (let i=0;i<4/*No se cuantos botones quieres agregar.*/; i++){
            let button=createElement("button");
            button.addEventListener("click",(i%2)?this.remove:this.toggle);/*Si el numero es par entonces ponemos la funcion toggle sino remove y asi lograremos esto 0: toggle, 1: remove, 2: toggle, etc...*/
            father.appendChild(button);
        }
    }
};
```